# Как вшить в программу информацию C#?

Tags: c#, защита

Хочу начать с небольшой предыстории и потихоньку подходить к делу.
Я программист самоучка, в последнее время заинтересовался защитой ПО на C#. Мне нужна помощь специалистов.

*Задача такова:*
 При первом открытии программы человек вводит текст в `textbox` и этот текст "вшивается" в программу, т.е при открытии на другом компьютере данного `.exe` будет выводиться то слово, которое было введено ранее. Я думаю, что осуществить это можно при помощи редактирования ресурсов программы. Нормальных статей я не нашел на эту тему, поэтому требуется ваша помощь. Идеи по реализации приветствуются!

Comment: Любой антивирус зарежет такую программу. И что мешает скопировать программу ещё до первого запуска?

Comment: Ну если брать задачу в том в виде как вы описали, то она не может быть решена

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov Не совсем понял, что вы имете ввиду

Comment: @Vasek из-за того, что идея реализовать это через ресурсы?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

С ресурсами не получится. [Здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20772976/reading-string-from-resource-file-and-editing-it-programmatically) написано почему. Если кратко - попробуйте удалить запущенный exe и вы поймете почему.

> заинтересовался защитой ПО

Если вы хотите таким образом сделать защиту, то она сработает только для "кухарок", все остальные более менее разбирающиеся люди это сломают очень быстро. Так что последуйте совету из ответа на который я дал ссылку выше. А именно... Просто создайте секретный файл или запись в реестре, это достаточно чтобы остановить "кухарок".

Comment: Не спорю, что такую защиту обойдут опытные люди. На данном этапе мне важна реализация, дальше буду уже выдвигать идеи наилучшей защиты, с использованием данной "технологии". Как я понимаю, изменить программу во время ее работы нельзя будет, соответственно надо будет запускать вторую, или вообще делать скрипт, который изменит внутренний ресурс .exe файла. А что, если изменять бинарный код программы, и в него впихивать нужную мне информацию? Как вам идея?

Comment: @Varagian Ну менять код программы из вне возможно. Для управляемых приложений(C# или Java) это даже не очень сложная задача. Но для этого вам понадобится тоскать утилиты для декомпиляции и обратной компиляции. Ну и конечно вам понадобятся минимальные знания [CIL](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Intermediate_Language)

Comment: т.е внешне изменять значение определенных переменных  в коде? Не спорю, будет не совсем просто, но я считаю, что это того стоит) Тем более, знания в подобных утилитах не будут лишними

Comment: @Varagian `т.е внешне изменять значение определенных переменных в коде?` ну да. Для начала рекомендую ознакомится с [ILSpy](https://github.com/icsharpcode/ILSpy#ilspy-------).